# AWS S3: Event notification configuration for [else/unmatched] [event/prefix/suffix]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filter, notifications, amazon-sns

In the notification document (link below) the examples for Notification Configurations, it explains that configurations with overlapping prefix/suffix combinations are invalid.

[Notification How To](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

However, there aren't any details for a way to catch any unspecified prefixes. If I had an S3 bucket with the directories dir1/ and dir2/, with a notification configuration like:

```
<NotificationConfiguration>
    <TopicConfiguration>
        <Topic>arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123412341234:sns-notify-dir1</Topic>
        <Event>s3:ObjectCreated:*</Event>
        <Filter>
            <S3Key>
                <FilterRule>
                    <Name>prefix</Name>
                    <Value>dir1</Value>
                </FilterRule>
            </S3Key>
        </Filter>
    </TopicConfiguration>
    <TopicConfiguration>
        <Topic>arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123412341234:sns-notify-dir2</Topic>
        <Event>s3:ObjectCreated:*</Event>
        <Filter>
            <S3Key>
                <FilterRule>
                    <Name>prefix</Name>
                    <Value>dir2</Value>
                </FilterRule>
            </S3Key>
        </Filter>
    </TopicConfiguration>
</NotificationConfiguration>
```

Is it possible to add a catchall filter? I know that overlapping rules don't work, so I can't just add:

```
<TopicConfiguration>
    <Topic>arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123412341234:sns-notify-generic</Topic>
    <Event>s3:ObjectCreated:*</Event>
</TopicConfiguration>
```

I'd like to know if I can have a more generic SNS notification in the event that an object is added under a 3rd directory, or in no directory, while still handling the first two cases specifically. Specifically, I'd like a filter that only catches things that haven't already been filtered, though I would also be happy with the ability to send multiple notifications (such as sending sns-notify-dir1 and sns-notify-generic for dir1, but just sns-notify-generic for dir3).

```
dir1/  -> Handled by sns-notify-dir1
dir2/  -> Handled by sns-notify-dir2

/      -> How can I handle with sns-notify-generic?
dir3/  -> How can I handle with sns-notify-generic?
```

I realize that alternative solutions will work, such as only writing a generic SNS and having my utilities sort out whether to listen to it, as well as sending everything to a lambda function to sort out which notification to trigger. However, I like the idea of coding this as cleanly as possible, if it is possible.

Please let me know if additional details would help, and thank you!

Comment: Why are configurations with overlapping prefix/suffix combinations are invalid?  What would be the harm in notifying two different SQS queues when one S3 event occurs?  Why was AWS designed like this?